# Definition of limit superior in terms of cluster points

Tags: real-analysis

Recently, my Real Analysis professor mentioned that the limit superior of a bounded sequence $(x_n)$ is the largest cluster point of $(x_n)$. We have been using the following definition for cluster points:
Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ be nonempty and $x\in \mathbb R$. We say $x$ is a cluster point of $A$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, $V_\epsilon(x)=(x - \epsilon,x + \epsilon)$ and $ A\setminus\{x\}$ are not disjoint.

In this case, would it be that $A$ is the set of cluster points of $\{x_n \ | \ n \in \mathbb N\}$, then $\limsup x_n = \sup A$? What is the correct and complete definition of the limit superior of a sequence involving cluster/accumulation points?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. (Moreover, $\limsup x_n \in A$)